# I receive the error code: AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chromium.service' has no attribute 'Service'

Tags: python, selenium, spyder

I am trying to install selenium in spyder. I think i finally did it, but keep receiving this error code with this code

```
from selenium import webdriver

web = "https://www.google.com/"
path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

#execute chromedriver with edited options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(web)
```

error code:

```
AttributeError: module 'selenium.webdriver.chromium.service' has no attribute 'Service'
```

Any help on how I can fix this?

I tried googeling the error code, but nothing came up.

Comment: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path)` try this.

Comment: If I use that I get a different error: `SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':`. Could it be I installed selenium wrong?

Comment: Alright I fixed it, had the wrong version of chromedriver.